# "Here's the optic"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from a documentary film where the narrator talks about putting things in perspective.

> If you break that down to how many per day or how many per hour, basically what you are getting is the equivalent of a Boston  Marathon bombing every half hour of every day of every week of ever year. So **here's the optic**. You've got the situation in the Boston Marathon bombing where a number of people died in the explosion. It was a terrible thing... But then meanwhile two days later a fertilizer plant blows up in Texas, killing more people.

It appears the line "Here's the **optic**" means *To put things in perspective,* but I can't find a dictionary definition of **optic** that fits in the context. What does **optic** mean exactly here? Is this a common usage?

Comment: See at EL&U *[What is the origin of the word “optics” that's prevalently used now in politics?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80574)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase **the optics** in the plural is often used to mean "how it will seem to the public" or "the facts on the ground from a public relations perspective".

I'm not quite sure what to make of the singular.  Perspective, perhaps?  Presentation from a particular point of view?  Showing two things side by side in order to get a sense of perspective, the underlying metaphor being  focal distance.

Answer (score 2):

You are interpreting the phrase correctly.  It's not common to say "here's the optic," but in general it just refers to the perspective / seeing / visual synonyms.

For example, you could also interpret "Here's the optic" to mean, "Here's another way of seeing things."